# How to Remove or add 2 rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to remove the current `<tr>` and the yellow `<tr>` too when I click to the basket icon on the right.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Here is my html code of the two rows which I want to delete by the click:

```
<tr>
              <td class="bar_td" colspan=7>
                <strong>PRESTATION 2</strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ligne_suppr">
              <td class="jr_td">
                <img class="jour_prest" src="img/ico/jour_presta.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" /> Mardi 24 jan 2011
                <p>ou</p>
                <img class="jour_prest" src="img/ico/jour_presta.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" /> Mercredi 25 jan 2011
              </td>
              <td class="cr_td">
                <select>
                  <option value="h9">10h30</option>
                  <option value="h10">11h30</option>
                </select>
                <select>
                  <option value="h11">10h30</option>
                  <option value="h12">11h30</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td class="rp_td">
                <select>
                  <option value="h13" SELECTED>2h00</option>
                  <option value="h14">3h00</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td class="mn_td">
                <select>
                  <option value="h15">2h00</option>
                  <option value="h16" SELECTED>6h00</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td class="tt_td">
                <strong>8h.</strong>
              </td>
              <td class="pttc_td">
                <strong>148 &#8364;</strong>
              </td>
              <td class="cor_td">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="img/ico/corbeille.png" alt="" width="13" height="13" />
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

and the Javascript code :

```
<script>
          $(".ligne_suppr a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ($(this).parent()).parent().remove();
          })
        </script>
```

But with this code I can only remove the big `<tr>` and the yellow One stays.

Have you any idea?

Comment: if you want a jquery answer, you have to tag it jquery too.

Comment: Sorry @Starx I'm not a professional of Javascript and JQuery, so ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.ligne_suppr a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = $(this).parent().parent();  // parent <tr> of the anchor tag
  var previous = parent.prev();        // <tr> before the parent <tr>

  parent.remove();
  previous.remove();
});
```

Comment: No, you're right :) Now the OP has to choose from two possibilities - that's good :)

Comment: I had already try the Vapire's one and it works perfectly ^^'

Answer (score 1):

This is basically going to tough to do when you dont have a specific way to select the two rows.

Create a global javascript function to remove the elements by taking the element's id

```
function deleteRows(row, yellow) {
    row = document.getElementById(row);    
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

    yellow = document.getElementById(yellow);
    yellow.parentNode.removeChild(yellow);
}
```

Using jQuery you can do something like this

```
$(".ligne_suppr a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toprow = $(this).closest("tr");
    toprow.prev().remove(); // remove the yellow
    toprow.remove(); // remove the row
});
```